# HighCharts Bullet Chart appears to ignore xAxis minTickInterval

Tags: charts, highcharts, bullet

See this JSFiddle of a bullet chart showing decimal values in the x-axis.
https://jsfiddle.net/5az19o2t/

I've tried to remove the decimals with the following options:

```
{ xAxis: { minTickInterval: 1, tickInterval: 1, allowDecimals: false }}
```

None of those options appear to do anything.  How can I define the tick intervals on a Bullet Chart?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, and then maybe someone can explain to me why it is.

Placing those settings on the Y-Axis config does adjust the chart.  Doesn't basic charting 101 dictate that X-Axis is left to right, and Y-Axis is up and down?

```
{yAxis: minTickInterval: 1} or {yAxis: allowDecimals: false}
```

both work.

Comment: Notice that you have `chart.inverted` option set to `true`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted